# Why does $_POST return multi array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have the following HTML form

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="process.php">
<table width="271" border="1">
<tr>
  <td width="5"><input name="txtIdone2" type="text" id="txtIdone2" value="Richard" /></td>
  <td width="250">
  <label for="txtIdone"></label>
  <input name="txtIdone" type="text" id="txtIdone" value="Hopes" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="txtIdone3" type="text" id="txtIdone3" value="Testing" /></td>
  <td><input name="txtIdone4" type="text" id="txtIdone4" value="this" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="txtIdone5" type="text" id="txtIdone5" value="it" /></td>
  <td><input name="txtIdone6" type="text" id="txtIdone6" value="works" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btnTest" id="btnTest" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

That submits to process.php that has the following code:

```
    $data = array($_POST);
print_r ($data);
```

Simple. However, instead of a regular array being returned, i'm receiving a multi array. Here is an example:

> 

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [txtIdone2] => Richard
            [txtIdone] => Hopes
            [txtIdone3] => Testing
            [txtIdone4] => this
            [txtIdone5] => it
            [txtIdone6] => works
        )

)
```

I just want a regular array returned. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is [already an array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

By doing `$data = array($_POST);` you are making the array multidimensional.

Try doing simply:

```
print_r($_POST);
```